# Newtonsoft Putting new property in JObject at the right place

Tags: json.net

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
{
  "Node": "Fruit.Color",
  "Response": "Green"
}
```

How can I create an JObject which looks like this:

```
{
  "Fruit": {
    "Color": "Green"
  }
}
```

I am messing around with Jobjects and such but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick

```
            JToken jToken = response;
            foreach (var str in node.Split('.').Reverse())
            {
                var obj = new JObject
                {
                    { str, jToken }
                };

                jToken = obj;
            }
```

No idea if it is the best option ...